# Emberjs calculate from form input and display answer

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Super coding n00b here. I'm trying to create a nutrition calculator in emberjs. If I have a user input form like below, where do I write the calculation function and how do I display the answer?

```
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="weight">Weight</label>
        {{input type="text" id="weight" class="form-control" value=weight}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="runduration">How long will you be running? (hours)</label>
        {{input type="text" id="runduration" class="form-control" value=runduration}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cycleduration">How long will you be cycling?</label>
        {{input type="text" id="cycleduration" class="form-control" value=cycleduration}}
      </div>
      <button {{action calculate}}>Calculate nutrition</button>
    </form>
```

Would I write the function in the controller?

In my router, I have the following, but I'd rather just keep the input form and displayed calculation on the same template nutritioncalc.hbs

```
  this.route('nutritioncalc');
  this.resource('new-nutritioncalc', { path: '/nutritioncalc/new' });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ember fills those `value=variable` with data inside input field.
You can access them in your `NewNutritioncalcController`.

```
App.NewNutritioncalcController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    calculate: function(){
      var weight = this.get('weight'),
          runduration = this.get('runduration'),
          cycleduration = this.get('cycleduration');
    }
  }
});
```

### Action Bubbling

Actions propagate from associated controller to chain of routes.

#### Documentation

Here is [action bubbling documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_action-bubbling).

If the controller does not implement a method with the same name as the action in its actions object, the action will be sent to the router, where the currently active leaf route will be given a chance to handle the action.

### Two Way Binding

Here is a blog post about [two way data binding in Ember](http://voidcanvas.com/emberjs-tutorial-two-way-data-binding/).

No matter whether you change the property in your template (for example typing in a textbox) or in javascript (for example by clicking a button), in both the cases, the change is reflected to all the places that the property or variable is used.